# Problem with deployment of SQL Server Database on Azure DevOps

Tags: sql-server, deployment

We have problem with deploy database via Azure Devops from Database solution:

```
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6741963Z Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6742889Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.DeploymentScriptDomGenerator.UnbindTableDatamotion(SqlTable sourceTable, SqlTable targetTable, Boolean unbindPartitionScheme, HashSet`1 unboundColumns)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6744135Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.DeploymentScriptDomGenerator.GenerateUnbindTableSteps(SqlTable sourceTable, SqlTable targetTable)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6746179Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.DeploymentScriptDomGenerator.GenerateSteps(Int32 operation, IModelElement element)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6747124Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.Analyzers.PlanMediator.BuildDependencyOrderedSteps(Int32 operation, List`1 classOrder, List`1 operationOrder, Dictionary`2 changes, Boolean preserveGraphs, Dictionary`2& relating, Dictionary`2& related)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6747886Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.Analyzers.PlanMediator.BuildOperations()
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6748373Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.OnGeneratePlan()
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6748954Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentPlanGenerator.GeneratePlan(List`1 drops)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6749433Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.BuildPlan()
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6749865Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.Controller.CreatePlan()
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6750293Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__1()
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6750692Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action action)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6751115Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__0(Object operation, CancellationToken token)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6751530Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6751996Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6752488Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6752950Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6753456Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext context)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6753964Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6754586Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName, DacDeployOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, Action`3 reportPlanOperation, Boolean executePlan)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6757007Z    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6757864Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.<>c__DisplayClassd.<DoDeployAction>b__2(DacServices service)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6758615Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.ExecuteDeployOperation(CommandLineArguments cmdlineArgs, String connectionString, String filePath, String modelFilePath, MessageWrapper messageWrapper, Boolean sourceIsPackage, Boolean targetIsPackage, Boolean authType, String tenantId, String customAuthArgs, Func`1 generateScriptFromPackage, Func`2 generateScriptFromDatabase)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6759486Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.DoDeployAction(DeployArguments deployArgs, Action`1 writeError, Action`2 writeMessage, Action`1 writeWarning, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CommandLineArguments cmdlineArgs)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6760035Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.DoDeployActions(CommandLineArguments parsedArgs)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6760422Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.PerformAction(CommandLineArguments parsedArgs)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6760761Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Run(String[] args)
2022-01-26T09:10:26.6761067Z    at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

What is also strange, when we deploy project on empty database all is working. Problem starts when we would like to deploy on existing database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmm this error usually is related to a sqlpackage not up to date.

The problem is not rising against a new database because it does not need to do a schema compare. Try to update the dacfx in the target server.

Comment: thank you for response. Could you please send instructions how to update dacfx on server ?

Comment: you have to download and install it. these are the links:
https://github.com/microsoft/DacFx
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15